# AirPort Extreme "An unexpected error occured." after factory reset

Tags: wifi, airport, time-capsule

With nothing else to do today, I decided to solve the lingering connectivity problems in the back yard. I have an old AirPort Extreme that I replaced with a Time Capsule many years ago, so I thought I would put that in the garage and pull some outdoor Ethernet.

The system came up immediately when I plugged it in, and as expected I got a blinking amber light. I opened AirPort Utility on my Mac and plugged the Extreme into the TC using an Ether. It asked for a password, but I had no idea what it might be, so I did a factory reset.

After the reboot, the system appears as a new WiFi device in Other Wi-Fi Devices in AirPort Utility under the "New AirPort Base Stations" group, which is what I would expect. However, when I select it in the menu, after briefly saying "Joining AirPort Extreme", a large dialog box appears:

"An unexpected error occured. Try again"

Off to a great start! I tried another reset, as well as a power cycle, same outcome.

Where to go from here?

Comment: Which AEx?  The flat one, or the tower?  I disremember when Airport Utility stopped supporting the flat-pack one.  Also, presumably you are within range of it.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to it over Ethernet rather than wifi, for the initial setup?

Comment: Marc - the flat one. It is sitting beside my computer. Tersujin, yes, I tried wired and wifi, same result.